# How to find missing files between specific date range?

Tags: files, find

I want to navigate through all the files in a folder and find out the missing file for a specific date.

Files are partitioned by hour and file name have `yyyy-mm-dd-hh` formatting.

So between `2017-07-01` and `2017-07-02` there will be 24 files from `2017-07-01-00` through `2017-07-01-23`

How can I find missing hourly file if I pass above dates as start and end date?

Appreciate any input!

Comment: For anyone else viewing this page, you are very likely to find a lot of use in the [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) collection of tools.  :)  (I'm not affiliated, btw, I just found them to solve my own problem.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# presuming that the files are e. g. template-2017-07-01-16:

# To test a given date
for file in template-2017-07-01-{00..23}; do
  if ! [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    echo "$file is missing"
  fi
done

# To test a given year
year=2017
for month in seq -w 1 12; do
    dim=$( cal $( date -d "$year-$month-01" "+%m %Y" | awk 'NF { days=$NF} END {print days}' )
    for day in $(seq -w 1 $dim); do
        for file in template-${year}-${month}-${day}-{00..23}; do
           if ! [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
             echo "$file is missing"
           fi
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: Why did you put the `!` outside of the brackets?  Is this because double brackets?  I normally would write that as `if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then` so I'm wondering if I'm wrong for doing that or what the difference is?  It appears to work either way for me.

Comment: Either will work; it's a question of if your thinking is more in line with "if ( not foo )" or "if not (foo)"; they're logically indistinguishable in this case.  They're "If not (file exists)" and "If (file does not exist)".

Comment: I am getting error here:                                                                                
 cal $( date -d "$year-$month-01" "+%m %Y" | awk 'NF { days=NF} END {print days}'                                                                                                      I can run this                                                                                                cal $(date +"%m %Y") | awk 'NF {DAYS = $NF}; END {print DAYS}'                        any specific reason why the former is not working ?

Comment: Are you running GNU `date` or BSD `date`?

Comment: The way you found the last day of each month is seriously slick! It will even effortlessly handle leap years.

Answer (score 6):

On a GNU system:

```
#! /bin/bash -
ret=0
start=${1?} end=${2?}
t1=$(date -d "$start" +%s) t2=$(date -d "$end" +%s)

for ((t = t1; t < t2; t += 60*60)); do
  printf -v file '%(%F-%H)T' "$t"
  if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
    printf >&2 '"%s" not found\n' "$file"
    ret=1
  fi
done
exit "$ret"
```

Note that on the day of the switch to winter time (in timezones that implement daylight saving), you may get an error message twice if a file is missing for the hour of the switch. Fix `$TZ` to UTC0 if you want 24 hours per day for every day (for instance, if whatever creates those files uses UTC time instead of local time).

Comment: `-e` will also match non-regular files (e. g. sockets, directories, et cetera).

Comment: @DopeGhoti, true, though the OP didn't specify the type of file he was looking for, nor what should be done if a file was found but with the wrong type (assuming a specific type is expected). Note that `[[ -f file ]]` also returns true for files of type _symlink_ provided the symlink resolves to a regular file. Also note that `[ -e file ]` would return false if `file` was a symlink that can't be resolved by the `bash` process.

Comment: What does `start=${1?}` do? If it was `${1:?}` it would throw an error for a missing parameter, but I don't see what it means without the colon. And, since I don't see a `-e` anywhere, it won't stop the script. Also, it took me awhile to figure out the magic of that printf statement. That's a lot of work getting done in a tiny command!

Comment: @Joe, `${1?}` exits the shell (regardless of `set -e`) with an error if the first argument is not supplied. `${1:?}` would exit the shell if it was not supplied or if it was supplied but as an empty string. That's standard Bourne and POSIX syntax.

Comment: @Joe I had the same question and found this: [Parameter Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16753536/2913477). From there - "the <colon> in the format shall result in a test for a parameter that is unset or null; omission of the <colon> shall result in a test for a parameter that is only unset. If parameter is '#' and the colon is omitted, the application shall ensure that word is specified (this is necessary to avoid ambiguity with the string length expansion)."

Answer (score 4):

What about command like below:

```
 grep -Fvf <(find * -type f \( -name "2017-07-02-00" $(printf " -o -name %s" 2017-07-02-{01..23}) \)) \
           <(printf "%s\n" 2017-07-02-{00..23})
```

```
ls
2017-07-02-01  2017-07-02-06  2017-07-02-08  2017-07-02-14  2017-07-02-19
2017-07-02-04  2017-07-02-07  2017-07-02-11  2017-07-02-15  2017-07-02-22
```

The output after command ran:

```
2017-07-02-00
2017-07-02-02
2017-07-02-03
2017-07-02-05
2017-07-02-09
2017-07-02-10
2017-07-02-12
2017-07-02-13
2017-07-02-16
2017-07-02-17
2017-07-02-18
2017-07-02-20
2017-07-02-21
2017-07-02-23
```

Above we are generating all possibilities of 24 files using `printf` and pass it to `find` its `-name` parameter which `printf` also helping her, then with `grep` command we are printing those files are exist in our *pattern* but `find` didn't find them.

Answer (score 1):

**Usage:** `./diff_date.sh 2017-08-30-00 2017-09-02-00`

```
#!/bin/bash

# This processing is needed, because `date` require 2017-08-30 00 format,
# not 2017-08-30-00. So, last dash is replacing by space in here.
start=$(sed 's/-/ /3' <<< "$1")
end=$(sed 's/-/ /3' <<< "$2")

while [[ "$start" != "$end" ]]; do
    # Returns dash back to its place and checks - does this file exist. 
    if [ ! -f "${start/ /-}" ]; then 
        echo "${start/ /-}"
    fi  
    # Performance of this code can be improved, by calling `date` only when
    # day is changing, not the every hour.
    start=$(date -d "${start} + 1 hour" "+%F %H")
done
```

**Testing:**

```
# make files
$ touch 2017-08-{30..31}-{03..23}; touch 2017-09-{01..02}-{03..23}
$
$ ./diff_date.sh 2017-08-30-00 2017-09-02-00
##### Output - missing files. #####
2017-08-30-00
2017-08-30-01
2017-08-30-02
2017-08-31-00
2017-08-31-01
2017-08-31-02
2017-09-01-00
2017-09-01-01
2017-09-01-02
```

Comment: +1 - I would just feel better if `[[ "$start" != "$end" ]]` was `[[ "$start" <= "$end" ]]`. I'm not sure about the `=` - to catch the last possible missing value. The main point is to avoid an infinite loop if start isn't less than end.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use egrep?  you can then regex it the way you want.

```
 egrep (2017-07-0[1-2]-\d\d$) *file name here*| tail
```

regex might be a little off - sorry.

Comment: from `egrep --help`: `Invocation as 'egrep' is deprecated; use 'grep -E' instead.`