# How to list directory names that do not contain a certain filename?

Tags: grep, find, directory, filenames

I have several hundreds of directories and in each of these directories there are files with date in their filenames, like this:

```
$cd dir1
$ls 
20190915.file.gz
20190916.file.gz
20190917.file.gz
...
```

Sometimes it happens that a certain file does not get generated in a certain folder. Continuing from the previous example, file *20190916.file.gz* might be missing in dir2:

```
$cd dir2
$ls
20190915.file.gz
20190917.file.gz
...
```

How could I list only directory names that do not contain *20190916.file.gz*?

`$find . | grep 20190916` would list all folders that do contain this file, so basically I only need to somehow reverse the output of this command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find missing files between specific date range?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385279/how-to-find-missing-files-between-specific-date-range) in my own answer there, you need yo modify command to `grep -Fvf <(find * -type f \( -name "20190901.file.gz" $(printf " -o -name %s" 201909{01..30}.file.gz) \)) <(printf "%s\n" 201909{01..30}.file.gz)`; which it will report missed files for that month. you can code `$(date ….)` inplace of hard_coded dates there as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the directories are not nested, loop through the directories and check for the presence of the file in each directory.

```
for d in */; do
  if ! [ -e "$d/20190916.file.gz" ]; then
    echo "Missing $d/20190916.file.gz"
  fi
done
```

Comment: that's neat. I also modified the if statement to "if ! [ -e "$d/$1" ];" so that I could provide the filename as a parameter for the script. cheers!